# Multiple SSRS IIF statement on one line

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report where I need to accomplish 3 tasks in one query.

```
=IIF (Fields!Name.Value = " "," ", & vbcrlf & Name)

=IIF (Fields!Lastname.Value="" ," ", & vbcrlf & lastname)

=IIF(Fields!Middle.Value = " "," ", & vbcrlf & Middle)
```

So what I'm trying to do it run those queries on one line and output the name, lastname and middle name on different lines

```
=IIF(Fields!Name.Value is nothing," ", & vbcrlf & Name, IIF(Fields!Lastname.Value is nothing," ", & vbcrlf & lastname), IIF(Fields!Middle.Value is nothing," ", & vbcrlf & Middle))
```

It doesn't seem to run, it just prints False.

Can someone please help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work...

```
=IIF(LEN(Fields!FirstName.Value) = 0 , "", Fields!FirstName.Value + vbcrlf )
+ IIF(LEN(Fields!MiddleName.Value) = 0 , "", Fields!MiddleName.Value + vbcrlf )
+ IIF(LEN(Fields!LastName.Value) = 0 , "", Fields!LastName.Value )
```

Here's some sample data with the results. It includes names that are `NULL` and empty strings and handles both by testing the length of the field.

[image]

*If you want blank lines so it always returns 3 lines then move the `+ vbcrlf` to outside the closing parentheses on each each.*

Comment: Thanks @Alan, this is absolutely fantastic. I didn't even have to change anything - it worked like charm. I appreciate your effort and help with this code.. stay safe :-)

Comment: just noticed in a copy/paste frenzy I left the last `+vbcrlf` in, which you don't really need.